# Pandas dataframe changing 2 columns values based on another columns value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with the following values:

| id | Count | Exposure | pct_affected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 4 | 150,000 | 1.2 |
| 104 | 0 | 150,000 | 1.2 |

When I merged my 2 dataframes, the values from one carried onto the other. I need to set both columns `Exposure` & `pct_affected` to 0, when `count = 0`. Otherwise they retain their values.

I tried the mask option & that doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did my answer help with your problem? If it did, consider accepting it so others can use it as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use Numpy's [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to check if `Count==0` and set the value of each column to 0 or to keep the original.

Full code (including importing libraries and data):

```py
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Add data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[104, 104], 
                   'Count':[4, 0], 
                   'Exposure':[150000, 150000], 
                   'pct_affected':[1.2, 1.2]}).set_index("id")

# Define list of columns to set 0 if Count==0
lst_cols_to_set_to_0 = ["Exposure", "pct_affected"]

# If Count==0, set value to 0, else keep original value
for c in lst_cols_to_set_to_0:
    df[c] = np.where(
        df["Count"] == 0,  # check
        0,                 # if check true, set to 0
        df[c]              # if check false, keep original
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

a = {'id':[104, 104], 'count':[4, 0], 'exposure':[150000, 150000], 'pct affected':[1.2, 1.2]}

b = pd.DataFrame(a)

b.loc[b['count'] == 0, ['exposure', 'pct affected']] = 0

print(b)

| id | count | exposure | pct affected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 4 | 150000 | 1.2 |
| 104 | 0 | 0 | 0.0 |

Comment: This worked. Thanks.